# The Pigeonhole principle and sum of integers in subset of Z

Tags: discrete-mathematics

S⊂{1,2,3,...} and the cardinality of S is 7. m is the maximum element in S.Find the possible values of m so that there exists distinct subsets B,C with s(B)=s(C) [s(B) means the sum of the objects in B and the same for C].The answer should be 7≤m≤21 (according to the answer section in my book).

I´m having problems accepting this because of the following:
Suppose m=23 and I am looking at the subsets of S having at most cardinality 6.There are 2^6-2=126 such subsets.Suppose B is such a subset.Then 1≤s(B)≤23+22+21+20+19+18,that is 1≤s(B)≤123.This would imply that m=23 is a part of the answer? Is there an error in the answer section in my book or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks like every $m\ge 7$ will work, because you can choose, for example,
$$S=\{1,2,3,4,5,m-1,m\} \qquad B=\{3,4,m\} \qquad C=\{1,2,5,m-1\}$$
As this example shows, you can even get $B\uplus C=S$ (which the problem as you quote it doesn't explicitly require, but which *a priori* could have been considered to be a harder problem).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but let´s say I have S={1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000}.Then m=1000000 and all the 127 nonempty subsets have different "sums". So,m=1000000 does not work?